# vue dynamic class wont respond on mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement a basic tooltip behavior, so when hovering a parent `div` the child `div` is being shown:

```
<div id="chart">
        <div
          v-for="skill in skills"
          :key="skill.name"
          class="skill"
          :style="{height: skill.height }"
          @mouseover="isHovered(skill, true)"
          @mouseleave="isHovered(skill, false)"
        >
          <div class="skill-tooltip" :class="{show: skill.isHovered}">{{skill.isHovered}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

each skill is an object like so:

```
 {
    name: 'someName',
    isHovered: false
 };
```

and `isHovered` is implemented as follows:

```
 isHovered(skill, action) {
      skill.isHovered = action;
    }
```

when logging the skill object i see the `isHovered` value has changed but the `show` class doesn't respond, any idea why?

Comment: Works for me. How/where you obtain `skills` array?

Comment: Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uL27y1tc/